# Not allowed to load local resource; QR code

Tags: php, yii, resources, local, qr-code

i;ve been working in **php, yii.**. i'm trying to load generated **QR codes** by an extension, here's a code to show the images :

```
public function actionShowBarcodeImage($id){

    $model = RgaContainerInventory::model()->findByPk($id);

    if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
        $this->renderPartial('application.modules.rgaContainerInventory.views.rgaLabelGenerator.showBarcodeImage', array(
                'img' => $model->barcode_label,
            ), false, true);
    }
}
```

In the view, it doesn't show the images, i opened up the console and had the error :

> **Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///C:/BitNami/wappstack-5.4.19-0/apac...**

The resource images are present, but i can't seem to find the problem. Some say, it has something to do with permissions? bitnami perhaps - server, htdocs folder or something like that? but what i've been searching talks about browser problems. I'm quite confused actually, need help Thank you.

Comment: my question isn't really about the extension. because the extension correctly generated the qr codes, i can even directly open them using image viewers. I was hoping to find answers relating to configuration or something like that why resource was denied to load.

Comment: Can you please post the code that calls this action via AJAX? If it's not being called via AJAX, there's your problem - the relevant code is only executed on an AJAX request. Also, the rest of the error text would be helpful.